# Android - How to pass HashMap<String,List<String>> between activities?

Tags: android

I want to pass HashMap object through intent. My Hashmap is contains String and List.
HashMap> listDataChild; I want to pass listDataChild to next activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(CURRENT CLASS.this, CLASS TO CALL.class);
                    intent.putExtra("test", YOUR HASHMAP);
                    startActivity(intent);
```

In another Activity get data like below:

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> data=(HashMap<String, List<String>>) this.getIntent().getSerializableExtra("test");
```

Comment: List<String> is not serializabe..You can pass ArrayList

Comment: I have define my list as List<String> list112 = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: so you can send as @pratik said.

Answer (score 0):

Attach it to the Intent as part of a `Bundle`.  `HashMap` is `Serializable` so it will work in a `Bundle` or even as a `Extra` to the intent.