# How to pass HashMap<String,List<String>> from intent

Tags: android, hashmap

I have a code here and i want to pass the hash map function by clicking save button. I looked  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22405736/android-how-to-pass-hashmapstring-liststring-between-activities) but cannot find the solution for me.

oN Click the button i need to pass the hasmap.Anyone please help for this.My Codes is:

```
    btnsave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
    btnsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                expandableDataPump.getData();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ExpandableList.class);
 //HERE I NEED TO PASS HASHMAP
                intent.putStringArrayListExtra("details",(HashMap<String,>) expandableDataPump.getData());

                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You have an ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


        }
    });

}

public class ExpandableDataPump {
    public HashMap<String, List<String>> getData() {
        HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail = new HashMap<>();

        for (int i = 2; i < container.getChildCount(); i++) {
            if (container.getChildAt(i) instanceof RelativeLayout) {
                List<String> childs = new ArrayList<>();
                childs.add(((TextView)container.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.textout)).getText().toString());
                expandableListDetail.put(txtHeading.getText().toString(), childs);
            }
        }


        return expandableListDetail;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: what is your problem? are you getting any exception/crash?

Comment: While writing the code in intent red line appears and i cannot run it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it wrong, all [Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/intro/) are serializable, in order to pass hashmap into intent you use

```
putExtra(String key, Serializable obj)
```

and to get the array back from intent, you do

```
getIntent().getSerializableExtra(String key)
```

**Your Answer**

```
btnsave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
btnsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), S.class );
            intent.putExtra( "details", getData() );

            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You have an ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }
});

public HashMap< String, List< String > > getData() {
    HashMap< String, List< String > > expandableListDetail = new HashMap<>();

    for ( int i = 2 ; i < container.getChildCount() ; i++ ) {
        if ( container.getChildAt( i ) instanceof RelativeLayout ) {
            List< String > childs = new ArrayList<>();
            childs.add( ( ( TextView ) container.getChildAt( i ).findViewById( R.id.textout ) ).getText().toString() );
            expandableListDetail.put( txtHeading.getText().toString(), childs );
        }
    }
    return expandableListDetail;
}
```

Comment: intent.putStringArrayListExtra("details",(HashMap<String,>) expandableDataPump.getData());
 am i doing wrong here?

Comment: `how it relates to hash map` can  you explain what you are trying to say ?

Comment: sorry if you misunderstood..But should not i call Hash map function in putExtra?? please edit my code :)

Comment: @learnphase you asked `How to pass HashMap<String,List<String>> from intent` and I answered that, now if you have a problem with something else ask another question. What exactly is the problem you are facing ?

Comment: No, no one will edit your code and correct the mistakes you made. You need to do that yourself. That is the whole purpose of this site. You face a problem, you ask we answer and you correct your problem

Comment: how can i implement here..                 intent.putStringArrayListExtra("details",(HashMap<>) expandableDataPump.getData());

Comment: Your method `getData()` should not be in `ExpandableDataPump` class, just cust the getData() method and put it in the activity, no use `putExtra(String key, getData())` to pass data to another activity

Comment: I have a ExpandableDataPump class below that have getData function and contains hashmap. So i need to pass this fucntion of hashmap on upper class.

Comment: Why do you have created a class for a single method ?

Comment: I am kind of new to Android programming and Java in general, and I cannot work out what is causing this error.I looked over internet for codes and try to implement in mine...

Comment: Are you able to solve it or not ? using this solution. Your method getData() should not be in ExpandableDataPump class, just cust the getData() method and put it in the activity, no use putExtra(String key, getData()) to pass data to another activity

Comment: Thank u for for this. I study about your first answer and found the solution.Anyways i should have accept your answer yesterday but i could not get what you said..I study yesterday and found solution.

Comment: public class ExpandableDataPump {
        public List<String> getData() {
            List<String> childs = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 2; i < container.getChildCount(); i++) {
                if (container.getChildAt(i) instanceof RelativeLayout) {
                    childs.add(((TextView)container.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.textout)).getText().toString());

                }
            }
            return childs;

        } 
    } this is what i did :) thanks alot for help

Comment: it was my mistake that i could not get it at first

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by just following below instruction.

First Create class with implements Serializable as shown below.

```
public class DataWrapper implements Serializable{

    private HashMap<String,List<String>> hasmap;

    public DataWrapper(HashMap<String,List<String>> hasmap){
        this.hasmap= hasmap;
    }

    public HashMap<String,List<String>> getHashMap(){
        return  this.hasmap;
    }
}
```

In activity from where you want to pass `HashMap<String,List<String>>` put below code.

```
DataWrapper dw = new DataWrapper(expandableDataPump.getData());

Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ExpandableList.class);
intent.putExtra("details", dw);
startActivity(intent);
```

In your `ExpandableList` activity retrieve DataWrapper object and the retrieve your `HashMap` from that object as shown below.

```
try{
   Intent intent = getIntent();
   DataWrapper dw = (DataWrapper) intent.getSerializableExtra("details");
   HashMap<String,List<String>> hasmap = dw.getHashMap();
} catch(Exception e){
}
```

that's it. Its working for me.

Comment: it would have been fantastic if the code was related with my above code

Comment: @jitesh Why create another wrapper over hashmap ? until and unless user has a  custom class

Comment: Thanku alot for this..I have already accept the answer above..anyways this also works and thank you alot..

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
extras.putSerializable("HashMap",Hash_Map);
intent.putExtras(extras);
```

Instead of

intent.putStringArrayListExtra("details",(HashMap) expandableDataPump.getData());

```
btnsave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
btnsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        try {
            expandableDataPump.getData();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ExpandableList.class);
            intent.putExtra("details",(HashMap<String,>) expandableDataPump.getData());

            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You have an ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }
});
```

}

Comment: Use the below code that i mentioned.. no need to add extra.

Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ExpandableList.class);

            intent.putExtra("details",(HashMap<String,>) expandableDataPump.getData());

            startActivity(intent);

Comment: intent.putExtra("details",(HashMap<String,????>) expandableDataPump.getData()); This statement is incomplete

Comment: Use this (HashMap<String,List<String>> hasmap)

Comment: i did this before.But casting HashMap is redudant is said..So can we over come this?

Answer (score 0):

To pass the `HashMap`,

```
btnsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ExpandableList.class);
            intent.putExtra("details", expandableDataPump.getData());
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
});
```

To retrieve it in `ExpandableList`,

```
HashMap<String,List<String>> hashmap = (HashMap<String,List<String>>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("details");
```